# Are the roads in Norway in good condition?

Tags: driving, road-trips, norway

My family is planning to go on a trip to Norway.
We are going by plane and some friends said that when you go to Norway, you have to drive a lot with your car.
That's why we're going to use a rental car.

Since I'm unable to drive, my dad has to drive.
But it is very flat in Belgium, so he is not used to the mountains.

Are the roads in Norway in good condition or not, so that he won't have problems driving on it?

Comment: In general, I'd say in a better condition than the Belgian roads.

Comment: In Winter it is cold, dark and slippery.

Comment: I don't understand the question. How is the driver not being used to mountains relevant to the question about whether the roads are in good condition? It's like saying, "I'm not used to spicy food. Are there good restaurants in country X?"

Comment: @DavidRicherby As in, "My father is already going to be uncomfortable driving in Norway, are the roads in such a condition to make his anxiety about driving there worse?"

Comment: One thing to get used to would probably be a lot of slanted, sharp turns. But you should be fine, most places you would be going to don't involve going up a lot of mountains, for there are a lot of tunnels

Comment: https://tv.nrk.no/serie/distriktsnyheter-nordnytt/DKTR98021116/11-02-2016#t=2m53s

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It kind of depends where you're going but I've had experience driving in Norway when I traveled there a couple years ago. Their roads are generally in GREAT shape. In some places they have luminescent paint/markers on the road. Part of having such high taxes, great public services. To be fair that applies to their major roads and anything around cities. The country roads I drove on were pretty good. Its the remote roads and mountainous places that may not be maintained as often.
As it has been mentioned, winter does get very cold/slippery outside of Oslo and other major cities. The rental company may have winter tires on the vehicle in that case.

Comment: The roads anywhere in Norway are fine. Speaking as a Canadian, they are in waaaaayyy better shape; we kinda ought to be ashamed of ourselves.

Comment: +1, pretty much correct. OP: Be careful in rural areas and during icy/wet weather. Be very careful in mountainous regions.

Comment: I think we're going to go in the summer, just to be save

Answer (score 3):

I would also add to Daxxcat's answer that if you want to compare mountainous regions between France and Norway:

- The roads are in much better shape in Norway (for all the reasons told in Daxxcat's answer)
- Many roads have a speed limit of 60 in Norway (at least in the counties where I've been), whereas default speed limit is 90 in France, even in the mountainous roads (although small portions may have exceptions).

Comment: I'm not from France, but Belgium

Comment: I understood that, that was an example to say that, among mountainious roads the Norwgian ones are not that bad.